# Tableau Create a running sum by Quarter of year

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Rate table that changes Quarter on Quarter.

i.e

```
+--------+-------+------+
|   Q1   |       |      |
+--------+-------+------+
| Sales  |       | Rate |
| <1000  |       | 1%   |
| >=1001 | <2500 | 2%   |
| >=2501 |       | 3%   |
+--------+-------+------+
|   Q2   |       |      |
+--------+-------+------+ 
| Sales  |       | Rate |
| <1500  |       | 1%   |
| >=1501 | <3000 | 2%   |
| >=3001 |       | 3%   |
+--------+-------+------+
```

etc..

I have created a Quarter field :

```
if month([booking_date]) = 1 then 1 
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 2 then 1
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 3 then 1
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 4 then 2
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 5 then 2
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 6 then 2
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 7 then 3
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 8 then 3
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 9 then 3
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 10 then 4
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 11 then 4
ELSEIF month([booking_date]) = 12 then 4
END
```

And tried all types of ways to make the equivalent:

Qtly Cum. Sales

If Quarter = 1 then sum(Sales)
elseif Quarter = 2 then sum(sales)
etc...

So i would end up with

```
+-----------------+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+------+
|                 | Jan | Feb | March | April | May | June |
+-----------------+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+------+
| Sales           | 200 | 350 | 500   | 400   | 500 | 700  |
| Qtly Cum. Sales | 200 | 550 | 1050  | 400   | 900 | 1600 |
| rate            | 1%  | 1%  | 2%    | 1%    | 1%  | 2%   |
+-----------------+-----+-----+-------+-------+-----+------+
```

Comment: So, What exactly is the error ? All I understood was you have sales value you have to return every quarter so you make a field which checks the month and you return 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 based month. Where exactly are you stuck ?

Comment: All I can manage to do so far is make the cumulative Sales accumulate from January and not sum by quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your Quarters Field in the columns shelf -- it will partition your months by quarter, but you can hide this header later. Click on your [Sales] pill

1. Quick Table Calculation > Running Total
2. Compute Using > Pane (Across)

[image]

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for!